# Webpack @import order (scss, css) is not kept

Tags: node.js, webpack, css-loader, sass-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

**Current Result**

1. SimpleBar
2. Bootstrap
3. Main

**Desired Result**

1. Bootstrap
2. SimpleBar
3. Main

It seems that the ".css" files are bundled first.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/scripts/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'scripts/app.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles/app.css'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [
                                    'autoprefixer'
                                ]
                            },
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'fonts',
                            publicPath: '../fonts'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    watch: true
};
```

**src/scripts/app.js**

```
import '../styles/app.scss';
```

**src/styles/app.scss**

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~simplebar/dist/simplebar.css';
@import 'main';
```

Please note that "SimpleBar" doesn't come with a ".scss" file which will fix the problem. I also don't want to rename the ".css" file from the "node_modules" directory.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.1",
    "postcss": "^7.0.32",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
```

**#1 Solution (I don't really like it)**

**src/scripts/app.js**

```
import '../styles/vendor.scss'; // Bootstrap and other goodies
import 'simplebar/dist/simplebar.css';
import '../styles/main.scss';
```

Comment: I had the same issue and worked around it by renaming every .css file to .scss. Not ideal, but it works.